# How can I find my stolen android mobile?

Tags: android-device-manager

This morning one of my Android mobile has been stolen. I had ‘signed in’ in Google Crome and play store in that device with one of my gmail acount. I'm trying to find the mobile through’ device manager. But It says ‘location unavailable’. Is it because the stolen mobile is switched off or the stolen mobile isn't connected to the internet? My stolen mobile needs to be connected to internet so that I can locate the mobile? Or I can locate the mobile if it's just switched on and no longer connected to the internet? What happens if the thieft sign out my gmail account from Google? Please tell me

Comment: If your gps is ON on the phone, you should be able to locate device

Comment: what do you mean by 'gps'?

Comment: I mean GPS, location services whatever you call it.

Comment: Where's the option to activate this service on mobile? Do I need to use app for this or what ?

Comment: Go to settings>location you have on/off switch there. http://z42i.imgup.net/Screenshot8e0b.png But if you allredy lost phone you cant activate it so you probably wont find your phone.

Comment: GPS is the actual feature that tracks the location of your phone, not internet connection. If GPS is turned off, you can't track it. As far as I know, when you try to locate the device using Android Device Manager, your phone's GPS gets activated even if it was off. However, in order for your phone to be able to receive that command it should be connected to the internet. If your phone wasn't password-protected than the thief might have disconnected it.

Comment: @SarpSTA now I tried to locate my device via ADM with location turned off but connected to a wifi and it says: Online. Access to a device location is turned off. So no you can't locate it when location is off.

Comment: @ЈеднорукиКрстивоје It worked in my old phone, Samsung Galaxy Wonder. I never tried it again.

Comment: What happens if the thieft sign out my gmail account from Google? Please tell me

Comment: Will I still able to track the phone even if he signed out my gmail account from Google? What should I do for it ?

Answer (score 1):

GPS is global positioning system. It is the setting/function on a phone that allows satellites in space to triangulate a position on earth, thus determining where that position is on a map. Sometimes users disable this due to security concerns or concerns of privacy.

There are several ways such a setting could be disabled though, even if you did not disable it. A thief or someone who found the phone could have enabled airplane mode which makes data, network, and GPS services disabled. Unfortunately, the phone could also be off due to power depletion of the battery.

I would recommend calling the phone periodically each day, checking the location each day, changing your Gmail password (just in case - I'm a little paranoid), and trying anyway you can to contact the new owner of the phone if it does have an owner. Additionally, if you had avast or some other anti-virus program installed, those programs also offer device locating. If your phone's GPS is indeed enabled, perhaps your Google location settings didn't work properly but the anti-virus location services could still help you find the device.

Comment: Thanks a lot. can't I enable gps service through Google right now ?

Comment: Where's the option to activate this service on mobile? Do I need to use app for this or what ?

Comment: What happens if the thieft sign out my gmail account from Google? Please tell me

Comment: As far as I and my Google searches know, you cannot enable location services remotely for a cell phone or tablet device. If you have a device with Android on it in front of you, you can go to settings -> General Tab -> Location. In this location section, you can enable/disable location services. Also, you can enable/disable certain location services/features within some apps, but the android system settings are global, meaning you can disable location services for all apps. If the thief signed out of your google account, not Gmail, it could diminish options available to you.